# Adding a dollar sign to an ion-input

Tags: input, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I currently have this:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label sale floating>Sale Price< /ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" clearInput placeholder="$">< /ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

What I'd really like, is to add a $ to the front of any input so that when a user types in a number it appears with a dollar sign next to, or inside it. I'm finding this impossible currently. In a standard input I'd put the before or in a span or label preceding the input in order to make it work.

However with the Ion-item in an Ion-list it seems that adding a span breaks it, and I'm not sure how, using scss, to add it after. Head exploding stuff.

I've tried:

```
ion-label[sale]:before {
    content: "$";
}
```

On a whim, in hopes that would work. It does not.

Anyone experience this before and have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting question. The following should work because in practice I believe an `<ion-input>` gets translated to a standard HTML5 input in the DOM.

```
input[type=number]:before {
    content: "$";
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me to solve a similar issue. However shouldn't it be `::before`?

Comment: This helped me but for me it was : `ion-input[type=number]::before {
 content: "$";
}` now I am just trying to make it hidden whilst the input is not in focus

Comment: just as an FYI, I got what I wanted by doing `ion-input[type=number]:focus-within::before {
 content: "$";
}` This only shows the dollar sign when the input is in focus.  ideal for when you are using a floating label

Answer (score 3):

This is a great question and @Lightbeard's answer should be sufficient for most use cases. I want to share an alternative solution for this using [Angular Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

```
@Pipe({name: 'roundDollars'})
export class RoundDollarsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any) {
    return _.isNumber(value) ? "$"+Math.round(value) : 'Price Error';
  }
}

@Pipe({name: 'roundCents'})
export class RoundCentsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any) {
    return _.isNumber(value) ? "$"+value.toFixed(2) : 'Price Error';
  }
}
```

In the template, you can implement like this if you are using a form control:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label sale floating>Sale Price< /ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" formControlName="salePrice" value="{{ formControl.get('salePrice').value | roundDollars }}">< /ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

This has the disadvantage that it will pre-pend a '$' to the actual value submitted in your form. I store my data as a number rather than a string, so I put the '$' character on a disabled input lower in the form to display the total of several inputs.

This means the actual input where the user is typing does not show a '$' but that appears lower in the form.

My production template looks like this:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Monthly Total:</ion-label>
  <ion-input [disabled]="true" class="invisible" type="number" formControlName="monthlyFee"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<p class="offset-y-32">{{ detailsForm.get('monthlyFee').value | roundDollars }}</p>
```

My `.invisible` class simply sets `opacity: 0` so you can still use the line from the `ion-item`, while `.offset-y-32` moves the `<p>` text up 32 pixels.

Here is a [screen shot of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRf76.png)

Comment: This looks exactly what I want.  Where is the Underscore coming from?  What library ware you importing? lodash?